# Why does osr.SpatialReference return different values in python2 and 3?

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, python-2.7, python-3

Can somebody explain why the result of `osr.SpatialReference()` differ between Python 2 and 3?

```
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.SetFromUserInput('EPSG:28992')
sr.ExportToProj4()
```

In Python 2.7 this gives me

```
Out[15]: '+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs '
```

In Python 3 though, I get a different answer:

```
Out[14]: '+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.2369,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857,0.350733,-1.87035,4.0812 +units=m +no_defs'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The projections differ in the datum shift values for the conversion from Amersfoort datum to WGS84.

The first one is [tfm code 4833](http://epsg.io/28992-4833), and the second is [tfm code 15934](http://epsg.io/28992-15934).

GDAL 2.1.0 uses tfm code 4833, while GDAL 2.2.0 and later uses tfm code 15934. The change was done in https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/37081

According to the remarks, 4833 is the latest definition. See also https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/2487 for the difference.

If you want higher precision, you could use a grid shift file for the transformation, see http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Amersfoort-RD-New-td5293753.html

Comment: so his system uses different gdal versions?

Comment: Unless they compiled the Python bindings themselves, that seems likely.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Comment: @bugmenot123 it is not necessary to compile the Python bindings yourself, you can just exchange the csv files to get the transformation synchronous in both pythons.